# How to use EntityFramework to map a many to many relationShip in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I read a post from [EF with MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).The example used three tables with 1-to-many relationships. And with `StudendId` as the foreign key set up, I can directly call `Model.Enrollments`(model is of Student type ) in the view.
I'd like to know How could I set up a many-to-many relationship with two tables.

[image]

With a beginning:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id
    { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId
    { get; set; }
    public string Title
    { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription
    { get; set; }

    public string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags
    { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int TagId
    { get; set; }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    public string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }

    public string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts
    { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to call `Model.Tags` to get all the Tags related to a Post or call `Model.Posts` to get all the Posts belong to a Tag in the view. I guess I need a class something like

```
public class TagPost
{
    public int TagId{get;set;}
    public int PostId{get;set;}
}
```

But It looks like `TagId` and `PostId` both are foreign keys? I am not sure what to do.

Comment: var posts = dbContext.Post.Where(CONDITION);
var tags = posts.Tags.ToList(); Should you contain your tags related to you Post. This is a similar tutorial related to your question: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation

Comment: @DawoodAwan I can't see there's a such condition to filter all the Tags belong to a post  as the many to many relation needs to be set manually.

Comment: EF does the filter for you. When you do this: 
var post1 = dbContext.Post.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PostId ==1);
var tags = post1.Tags(); will have all Tags related to the PostId == 1

Comment: @DawoodAwan .I don't think `var tags = post1.Tags()` will work. Let's say I insert 5 records into table `db_post` with `Id` from 1-5. And I also insert 3 records into table `db_Tag` with `TagId` t1,t2,t3.  But I has not given EntityFramework any clue how to do the relationship mapping. So I think Before the `var tags = post1.Tags()`, It need some more steps.

Comment: In your question you asked about GETTING all Tags related to a post or getting all posts related to tag. Not INSERTING in a post with tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reading:**

```
var post1 = dbContext.Post.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PostId ==1);
 var tags = post1.Tags();
```

**Inserting:**

```
// Create a New Post Entity
var post = new Post();

// Assign it you values either from ViewModel or
    post.Title ="ManyToMany";
// Create your list of tags related to Post
    post.Tags = new List<Tags>();

// Add a Tag from Database to this List where TagId == 1
    post.Tags.Add(dbContext.Tags.First(s => s.TagId == 1));

// save Changes
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

after save Changes you will see that in you Many-to-Many Mappings table there is a new Record with

```
PostId = 2 // Considering you have PostId == 1 already in DB
TagId = 1 // Tag you added before dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: @I will give it try later today. Thank you.